# Is there a difference between sudo su - root and sudo -u root -H /bin/bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, su

Like title says, is there a difference between these two commands :

```
sudo su - root
sudo -u root -H /bin/bash
```

I'm using GNU/Linux, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to become root, the best way to do so is `sudo -i`, which simulates the initial login (giving you all the paths and variables associated with a root login). If you want to login without getting the root users *.files*, you could just use `sudo su` (no need to specify the root user).

Comment: `sudo -H /bin/bash` does run bash. The `-H` option doesn't take an argument.

Comment: -H just changes the $HOME to the target user's home directory.  That's it.  As the man page says, this might even be the default policy.

Comment: is there a source for this solution please?

Answer (score 7):

```
su - # causes the user to run a login shell aka bash --login
     # the same as if the user had logged in as the root from the login prompt
```

and `sudo su -` is the same as `sudo su - root` specifying root is redundant.

`sudo -u root -H /bin/bash` again the `-u root` is redundant, `sudo` runs as root by default but the `-H /bin/bash` is run as an sudoer, the env vars SUDO_USER, SUDO_UID and SUDO_COMMAND are set to the callers name/uid and bash respectively.

But in this case, bash is not run as a login shell.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, they can differ if root shell isn't /bin/bash - this is possible for tiny or embedded Linux environments, or traditional for BSD systems which prefer /bin/[t]csh for root user.
Also, `su -' drops all environment except a few variables related to the terminal. sudo's behavior on environment is configurable (see env_reset in /etc/sudoers).
So, be careful with details...

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference between the two commands you listed is that running `su -` will cause the shell to be a login shell.  That means that root's shell's login scripts will be executed (.bash_profile for example, if it's bash), the PWD will be set to $HOME, and certain parts of the user environment will be initialized.  `sudo bash` just runs a new shell as the target user's shell, and the -H just initializes one variable, $HOME, to the target user's home directory.  Other variables will not be set, and some will be carried over to the new shell, as defined in your sudo policy.